# Edit particular cell value in row using vaadin table

Tags: java, vaadin7

I am new to Vaadin 7. Am facing a problem with vaadin table. Currently my data displaying in vaadin table, in that table each row got one button. When I click that button, I want to change particular cell value in the same row.

Ex: In a row I have two columns "name" and "button". When I click button i want change name value in same row.

Here, I have tried sample code for above my issue:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
table.addContainerProperty("Click", Button.class, null);
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
Button bt_click = new Button("show");
bt_click.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
Notification.show("Trying");
}
});
 table.addItem(new Object[] {"ABC"+i, bt_click },i);
}
```

After that when I click a button in row, I have stuck how do I have to do change the column Name value inside button click event.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the item id using the Button's data field. It would look something like this:

```
        final Table table = new Table();
        table.addContainerProperty("Name", String.class, null);
        table.addContainerProperty("Click", Button.class, null);
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        final Button bt_click = new Button("show");
        bt_click.setData(i);
        bt_click.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Item item = table.getItem(bt_click.getData());
            item.getItemProperty("Name").setValue("New Name");
            Notification.show("Trying");

        }
        });
         table.addItem(new Object[] {"ABC"+i, bt_click },i);
        }
```